# Why vsftpd don't respect passive port range?

Tags: vsftpd

I configure vsftpd for passive mode

```
listen=YES
log_ftp_protocol=YES
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_address=192.168.0.2
pasv_min_port=10090
pasv_max_port=10100
```

It works but use random ports!

Look output of ss during transfer

```
tcp   ESTAB     0      0                            192.168.0.2:33150     192.168.0.2:21    users:(("ncftp",pid=14411,fd=4)) timer:(keepalive,119min,0) uid:1000 ino:236010 sk:400b cgroup:unreachable:1 <->    
tcp   ESTAB     0      0                            192.168.0.2:44985     192.168.0.2:20    users:(("ncftp",pid=14411,fd=7)) timer:(keepalive,119min,0) uid:1000 ino:246607 sk:4011 cgroup:unreachable:1 <->
```

this is ok..without firewall, with firewall and redirect port for nat is a serious problem
Why vsftpd use random ports?

I have tried

```
listen_ipv6=NO
```

and disable pasv_address option. But nothing

This is the complete configuration, actually

```
anonymous_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=NO
dirmessage_enable=YES
ftpd_banner=Welcome
listen=YES
listen_ipv6=NO
local_umask=022
log_ftp_protocol=YES
ls_recurse_enable=YES
pasv_address=192.168.0.2
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_max_port=10100
pasv_min_port=10090
seccomp_sandbox=NO
xferlog_enable=YES
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
xferlog_std_format=YES
```

I have tried it on Slackware 15 and Debian 12

This is an example:

ncftp works but don't respect the passive port range

ftp works, but don't respect the passive port range

```
ftp -p 192.168.0.2
Connected to 192.168.0.2 (192.168.0.2).
220 Welcome
Name (192.168.0.2:me): anonymous
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp> cd pub
250 Directory successfully changed.
ftp> get 4.mkv
local: 4.mkv remote: 4.mkv
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,2,39,112).
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for 4.mkv (12904291 bytes).
226 Transfer complete.
12904291 bytes received in 0,0272 secs (473899,78 Kbytes/sec)
```

Comment: (originating) port 20 means the client did not request passive FTP

Comment: Thanks I will try now

Comment: Nothing, same thing

Comment: You can use tcpdump/wireshark to capture and read back what happened.

Comment: I use tcpdump, and show connection passive to random ports (sometime 35000, sometime 42000, etc.)

Comment: The *content* of the capture, with FTP on-wire commands matters. not the ports of the packets. You cannot assume "passive" without reading the actual commands. ncftp might also have a debug mode for this. Port 20 means "not passive".

Comment: I have disabled port 20

Comment: Please show the client commands to connect to your server. Like in the commandline `ftp hostname.tld` then log in by username and password, then `PASV` then `LIST` then `GET filename` or `RETR filename`.

Comment: I have tried three different clients: ftp, ncftp, lftp

Comment: The commands, please. Add them as code to the question. `ftp` is easiest to understand and preferred. We need to exclude typos and the like which happens to everyone.

Comment: `227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,2,39,112).` uses port 39*256+112=10096 which is within the requested range 10090-10100 . Are you telling the transfer for this example used an other port?

Comment: Thanks, probably I found the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it **DID** what you said.

The client line reads:

```
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,0,2,39,112).
```

This is displaying a series of 6 **bytes**  (note the commas).  The port number is the last two.

39 * 256 + 112 = 10096.

Thus, it used port 10096, which is in your port range.

Comment: Yes I know, the problem was with ncftp and lftp which use random port

Comment: Well, yes, the client is free to use any port it wants.   I believe at one point, there was a practice of using port 20 on both ends.  That practice may have lasted a few years, but it is LONG gone.  (It inhibited having two connections between the sames hosts.)  And even in PORT mode, neither side needs to use port 20.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found: vsftpd is configured correctly
The problem was ncftp and lftp client which set a random port.